# How would one find out if a method is static using Java's reflection API?

Tags: java, reflection

If I didn't know that the `sleep` method on java.lang.Thread was static, how could I find out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`getModifiers`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers%28%29) on the `Method` object:

```
Method meth = ...;
if (Modifiers.isStatic(meth.getModifiers())) {
  // method is static
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 (myclass.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) != 0
```